# Repeat a RDLC ReportViewer subreport

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm really new to RDLC so please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

I have some data that needs to get repeated, based on a 1:Many dataset that's linked to the main report.  It's not something that can be displayed in a tabular fashion because the customers want it laid out in a specific manner, so using the Tablix control is out.  I have a number of subreports based on 1:1 datasets in this main report, and everything is cool with those.  I created a subreport for this new dataset and added it to the main RDLC report.  Everything works fine, but it only includes the first record of the dataset.

Is it possible to repeat this subreport for each record in the dataset?  I think the thing that confuses me is the main RDLC has no code that specifically loads the individual subreports, so I don't see anyplace obvious where I could include a loop or anything.

Comment: There should be [SubreportProcessing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.subreportprocessing.aspx) event which is triggered for every instance of the subreport in the main report. If a report contains multiple subreports instances from the same report definition, this event is triggered for each instance.

Comment: How could I use that information to repeat a subreport n number of times, with n being the number of records returned to the dataset that populates it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't have particular needs I think it's important to know that you can put a `Rectangle` in `Tablix` cell and then use it as a container for simple controls as `TextBox`, `Line`, `Image`, etc. laied out as you want.

If you still need to use subreport you could put a `SubReport` in `Tablix` cell and solve any problem in the [`LocalReport.SubreportProcessing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.subreportprocessing.aspx) event that occurs when a subreport is processed.

If you have a lot of records you can use a single `Dataset` and filtered it in the `SubreportProcessing` event, using the subreport `Parameters` that you already set in `Designer Mode`.

```
Private Sub SubreportProcessingHandler(sender As Object, e As SubreportProcessingEventArgs)

    Dim dvFiltered As New DataView(Me.YourDataSet.Tables(0))

    dvFiltered.RowFilter = "Parameter1 = " & CInt(e.Parameters.Item("yourParameter1").Values(0)) & " AND " _
        & "Parameter2 = '" & CStr(e.Parameters.Item("yourParameter2").Values(0)) & "'"

    e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("YourDataSourceName", dvFiltered.ToTable("YourDataSourceName")))

End Sub
```

For example, using a `DataSet` that contains master and details data, you can build a main report grouped by `IdMaster` and put a subreport in details section.

[image: main report]

This is the subreport: please note that the `DataSet` is the same as main report but we also need 2 `Parameters` (`IdMaster` and `IdRow`) to display the correct data.

[image: sub report]

In the main report you need to link subreport `Parameters` to actual values of `DataSet`.

[image: sub report parameter]

Then, the most important part: the `SubreportProcessingHandler` event. This event is triggered for every instance of the subreport in the main report, so if you have 100 rows / 100 subreports this event is triggedered 100 times: every time you need to specify which data you want to display, so you have to filter the `DataSet` using the 2 `Parameters` (`IdMaster` and `IdRow`) defined in the previous step and filled with values coming from master report.

```
Private Sub SubreportProcessingHandler(sender As Object, e As SubreportProcessingEventArgs)

    Dim dvTest As New DataView(Me.dsTest.Tables(0))
    dvTest.RowFilter = "IdMaster = " & CInt(e.Parameters.Item("parIdMaster").Values(0)) & " AND " _
        & "IdRow = " & CInt(e.Parameters.Item("parIdRow").Values(0))

    e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet_TEST", dvTest.ToTable("DataSet_TEST")))

End Sub
```

This is the result:

[image: result]

As I stated at the beginning of the answer, if you don't have particular needs you can use a `Rectangle` instead of a `SubReport`. Regarding this example you can obtain the same result using the green `Rectangle` as container.

[image: rectangle]

Comment: I put the subreport in a Tablix (I didn't even know you could do that...), but it still only shows the data in the first record.

Comment: We're close, just having a problem with all the data being repeated.  I think we need to integrate your filter, hopefully I can give this a check by the end of the day.

Comment: For the record, in case anyone else comes across this, for my purpose I just couldn't get it to work inside a subreport.  Maybe because in my case it was actually a sub-subreport.  However, adding a Rectangle object to the Tablix and laying out all of my fields inside it in the way I needed to see them worked perfectly.  Thank you!!